# OpenSSL speedup with cryptodev on i.MX6 CAAM

Tags: openssl, cryptoapi, hardware-acceleration, imx6

I am trying to utilize the CAAM hardware on the i.MX6 through cryptodev. The speedup looks good in the openssl speed benchmark. For example when running:

```
openssl speed -evp aes-256-cbc -engine cryptodev
```

I get good speedup and I can see the interrupts to the CAAM increasing rapidly in /proc/interrupts.
However I need to use the encryption in an application so I utilize the OpenSSL API functions for envelope encryption:

```
 int EVP_SealInit(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, const EVP_CIPHER *type, unsigned char **ek, int *ekl, unsigned char *iv, EVP_PKEY **pubk, int npubk);

 int EVP_SealUpdate(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *out, int *outl, unsigned char *in, int inl);

 int EVP_SealFinal(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *out,
             int *outl);
```

passing EVP_aes_256_cbc() as the const EVP_CIPHER *type.
Here I do not get any speedup and I also do not see the interrupts to the CAAM increasing in /proc/interrupts. Could anyone please guide me about what is wrong in this scenario? Why is the API call not utilizing the CAAM engine while the "openssl speed" benchmark is working fine?

Comment: Did you register the engine implementation of ciphers as defaults?

Comment: The priority for caam engine is highest (3000) so I expected it to be used by default. But this is my first time dealing with openssl so I am most probably wrong. Could you tell me how to register engine implementation? Could it be done through these: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Engine(3)

Comment: The link does not work but yes, that's where I would look for a solution. Seems like you need to initialize the engine and then call ENGINE_set_default_*.

Comment: That worked for me! I can now get the CAAM engine utilized. Thanks!